# Using は(wa) or が(ga)

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

So I'm trying to make a sentence which goes, "My effort is still not enough", and I came up with

"私の努力(__)まだ足りない。"

I was thinking about using wa, however since "足りない" is intransitive, I wondered if I should use ga instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say「私の努力」it follows that you would use は.

By saying 「私の努力」rather than just「努力」, the sentence already begins by singling the speaker out, so I think は would most naturally follow.

If you drop the「私の」you could naturally use は or が depending on the context.

Like...

*Your boss comes over to your desk to discuss a project that your team has been working on:*

> プロジェクトがまた失敗したね、ボビー君

```
Your project failed again, eh Bobby?
```

> そうですね。**私の努力は**まだ足りません。

```
Yeah, I'm just not putting in enough effort. 
(*Maybe if I tried something other than just putting in effort, 
things might have worked out differently...)
```

OR

> そうですね。**努力は**まだ足りません

```
Yeah, not enough effort is being put in.   
(*A lack of effort is the problem. Maybe it's me, maybe it's the team...)
```

> そうですね。**努力が**まだ足りません。

```
Yeah, not enough effort is being put in.   
(*Lack of effort is a problem, maybe there are other problems too...)
```